# RPC in Go: How can I use interface as the rpc reply

Tags: http, go, rpc

### I can't define a rpc with the interface reply :(

I've define a struct and interface like this:

```golang
type Animal interface {
  Init(string)
}

type Cat string

func (*c Cat) Init(s string) {
  *c = s
}
```

Now maybe I can say that the `cat` struct "implement" the `Animal` interface.And I want to register this api as a rpc.

Because there maybe a few different `Animal` will be added then. So I want to register the `Init` RPC with the interface value, and I do that:

```golang
type RPC struct{}
func (r *RPC) Init_rpc(p string, reply Animal) error{
    res := new(Cat)
    err := res.Init(p)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    reply = res
    return nil
}

func Register_rpc() {
    rpc_ani := new(RPC)
    rpc.Register(rpc_ani)
    rpc.HandleHTTP()
    l, e := net.Listen("tcp", ":1256")
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen error:", e)
    }
    go http.Serve(l, nil)
}
```

But there is an error called:

`rpc.Register: reply type of method "Init" is not a pointer: "Animal.Animal"`

I was so confused how can I register a RPC with the interface reply. Because I know that I can't have a pointer to an interface, so there is unworkable to change the Init_rpc like this:

```golang
func (r *RPC) Init_rpc(p string, reply *Animal) error{
    res := new(Cat)
    err := res.Init(p)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    reply = &res
    // or *reply = res
    return nil
}
```

Reference in Chinese about the pointer to interface: [Ref](http://www.singleye.net/2017/11/go%E8%AF%AD%E8%A8%80%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B%E9%99%B7%E9%98%B1/)

Maybe there is some way to achieve the goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Because I know that I can't have a pointer to an interface"  -- that's incorrect. You can certainly have a pointer to an interface and that's exactly what you should do here.

Comment: I've noticed that question. That link on this topic is incorrect, and that really misguide me.